# Power Automate Solution Instant Flow

Tags: solution-deployment, solution

I've read the MS article regarding importing existing flows into solutions.  [Solutions in Power Apps - Power Apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview#known-limitations)

I have a solution and a "manual 'flow (which I created within the solution).  It's simple, select an item in a list and get the properties...that's it...I'm just trying to get this to work.

When I export the solution from my Dev to Production and go to the target list, select an item, the flow does not show up in the dropdown (Automate menu).  My automated cloud flows work fine within the solution.

Is it not possible to use manual (aka Instant) flows within a solution at all.  The article above suggests if the instant flow is created within the solution it will work...it's not working.  Suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated as I'm trying to put all my flows into solutions at this  point.

Comment: What is the trigger used in flow? How you are attaching flow to SharePoint site list in production, using environment variable?

Comment: The flow trigger is a select item and i'm not using any environment variable (for now).  My only goal is to get the instant flow to work from the Production environment so when I select an item and select Automate I can see the flow.  That is not happening right now and I don't know why.  The flow doesn't do anything at this point except to get properties...that's it.